# How can I avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, loops

Suppose I have a dictionary of lists:

```
d = {'a': [1], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [], 'd':[]}
```

Now I want to remove key-value pairs where the values are empty lists. I tried this code:

```
for i in d:
    if not d[i]:
        d.pop(i)
```

but this gives an error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I understand that entries can't be added or removed from a dictionary while iterating through it. How can I work around this limitation in order to solve the problem?

---

<sub>See [Modifying a Python dict while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/) for citations that this can cause problems, and why.</sub>

Comment: In addition to the answers given below, you may consider checking for the empty list at the places where you remove element(s) from the list. You could write a helper function: `def remove_helper(d, k, elem): d[k].remove(elem); if not d[k]: del d[k]`.

Comment: There are, practically speaking, perhaps three meaningfully distinct ways to do this, and in my assessment every meaningful minor variation on those ways can be covered by considering at most 6 of the answers here. It's somewhat worrying that there are 8 more undeleted, and another 5 that were previously deleted.

Comment: @joseville to be clear: you propose updating the dict *when* lists *become* empty, rather than iterating to remove the empty lists? That could be a practical approach to the broader problem in context, depending on the exact original requirements. But I agree it doesn't justify a separate answer.

Answer (score 794, accepted):

In Python 3.x and 2.x you can use use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) to force a copy of the keys to be made:

```
for i in list(d):
```

In Python 2.x calling [`.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) made a copy of the keys that you could iterate over while modifying the `dict`:

```
for i in d.keys():
```

but on Python 3.x, `.keys` returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) instead, so it won't fix your error.

Comment: I believe you meant 'calling `keys` makes a copy of the ***keys*** that you can iterate over' aka the `plural` keys right? Otherwise how can one iterate over a single key?
I'm not nit picking by the way, am genuinely interested to know if that is indeed key or keys

Comment: Or tuple instead of list as it is faster.

Comment: To clarify the behavior of python 3.x, d.keys() returns an _iterable_ (not an iterator) which means that it's a view on the dictionary's keys directly. Using `for i in d.keys()` does actually work in python 3.x _in general_, but because it is iterating over an iterable view of the dictionary's keys, calling `d.pop()` during the loop leads to the same error as you found. `for i in list(d)` emulates the slightly inefficient python 2 behavior of copying the keys to a list before iterating, for special circumstances like yours.

Comment: your python3  solution is not work when you want to delete an object in inner dict. for example you have a dic A and dict B in dict A. if you want to delete object in dict B it occurs error

Comment: for python3 you can try `for i in list(d.keys()):`

Comment: In python3.x, `list(d.keys())` creates the same output as `list(d)`, calling `list` on a `dict` returns the keys. The `keys` call (though not that expensive) is unnecessary.

Comment: @DanielChin: That documentation is for the wrong version of Python. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items.

Answer (score 133):

You only need to use `copy`:

This way you iterate over the original dictionary fields and on the fly can change the desired dict `d`.
It works on each Python version, so it's more clear.

```
In [1]: d = {'a': [1], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [], 'd':[]}

In [2]: for i in d.copy():
   ...:     if not d[i]:
   ...:         d.pop(i)
   ...:         

In [3]: d
Out[3]: {'a': [1], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

(BTW - Generally to iterate over copy of your data structure, instead of using `.copy` for dictionaries or slicing `[:]` for lists, you can use `import copy` -> `copy.copy` (for shallow copy which is equivalent to `copy` that is supported by dictionaries or slicing `[:]` that is supported by lists) or `copy.deepcopy` on your data structure.)

Comment: `for key, value in dic.copy().items():`

Comment: Use of the `.copy()` method should be the accepted anwser.
Thanks.

Answer (score 71):

Just use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/dictionary-comprehension-in-python-explained-with-examples/) to copy the relevant items into a new dict:

```
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'c': [], 'b': [1, 2], 'd': []}
>>> d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

For this in Python 2:

```
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'c': [], 'b': [1, 2], 'd': []}
>>> d = {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v}
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: `d.iteritems()` gave me an error. I used `d.items()` instead - using python3

Comment: This works for the problem posed in OP's question. However anyone who came here after hitting this RuntimeError in multi-threaded code, be aware that CPython's GIL can get released in the middle of the list comprehension as well and you have to fix it differently.

Comment: Is dictionary comprehension the same as [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python)? Dictionary comprehension does not seem to be very popular (or in the official documentation). There is [PEP 274](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/), but was it implemented?

Answer (score 43):

This worked for me:

```
d = {1: 'a', 2: '', 3: 'b', 4: '', 5: '', 6: 'c'}
for key, value in list(d.items()):
    if value == '':
        del d[key]
print(d)
# {1: 'a', 3: 'b', 6: 'c'}
```

Casting the dictionary items to list creates a list of its items, so you can iterate over it and avoid the `RuntimeError`.

Answer (score 17):

To avoid "dictionary changed size during iteration error".

For example:  "when you try to delete some key",

Just use 'list' with '.items()'. Here is a simple example:

```
my_dict = {
    'k1':1,
    'k2':2,
    'k3':3,
    'k4':4
 
    }
    
print(my_dict)

for key, val in list(my_dict.items()):
    if val == 2 or val == 4:
        my_dict.pop(key)

print(my_dict)
```

#### Output:

```
{'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3': 3, 'k4': 4}

{'k1': 1, 'k3': 3}
```

This is just an example. Change it based on your case/requirements.

Comment: This approach is already covered by singrium's answer from 2020, and is a trivial variant of other approaches seen in the original answers from 2012.

Answer (score 15):

I would try to avoid inserting empty lists in the first place, but, would generally use:

```
d = {k: v for k,v in d.iteritems() if v} # re-bind to non-empty
```

If prior to 2.7:

```
d = dict( (k, v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if v )
```

or just:

```
empty_key_vals = list(k for k in k,v in d.iteritems() if v)
for k in empty_key_vals:
    del[k]
```

Comment: +1: last option is interesting because it only copies the keys of those items that need deleting. This may give better performance if only a small number of items need deleting relative to the size of the dict.

Comment: @MarkByers yup - and if a large number do, then re-binding the dict to a new one that's filtered is a better option. It's always the expectation of how the structure should work

Comment: One danger with rebinding is if somewhere in the program there was an object that held a reference to the old dict it wouldn't see the changes. If you're certain that's not the case, then sure... that's a reasonable approach, but it's important to understand that it's not quite the same as modifying the original dict.

Comment: @MarkByers extremely good point - You and I know that (and countless others), but it's not obvious to all. And I'll put money on the table it hasn't also bitten you in the rear :)

Comment: The point of avoiding to insert the empty entries is a very good one.

Answer (score 13):

For Python 3:

```
{k:v for k,v in d.items() if v}
```

Comment: Nice and concise. Worked for me in Python 2.7 also.

Comment: This approach was covered by the original answers.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot iterate through a dictionary while it’s changing during a *for* loop. Make a casting to list and iterate over that list. It works for me.

```
    for key in list(d):
        if not d[key]:
            d.pop(key)
```

Comment: This approach was covered by the original answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list to collect the keys that should be removed; then use the `pop` dictionary method to remove the identified keys while iterating through the list (a separate object, so the error will not occur).

```
d = {'a': [1], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [], 'd':[]}
pop_list = []

for i in d:
    if not d[i]:
        pop_list.append(i)

for x in pop_list:
    d.pop(x)

print(d)
```

Comment: This technique is mentioned in Jon Clements' answer from 2012, but using a comprehension for the first loop.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 does not allow deletion while iterating (using the *for* loop above) a dictionary. There are various alternatives to do it; one simple way is to change the line

```
for i in x.keys():
```

with

```
for i in list(x)
```

Comment: This approach was covered by the original answers.

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, I like to make a deep copy and loop through that copy while modifying the original *dict*.

If the lookup field is within a list, you can enumerate in the *for* loop of the list and then specify the position as the index to access the field in the original *dict*.

Answer (score 0):

- The Python **"RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"** occurs when we change the size of a dictionary when iterating over it.
- To solve the error, use the copy() method to create a shallow copy of the dictionary that you can iterate over, e.g., `my_dict.copy()`.

  ```
  my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

  for key in my_dict.copy():
      print(key)
      if key == 'b':
          del my_dict[key]

  print(my_dict) # ️ {'a': 1, 'c': 3}
  ```
- You can also convert the keys of the dictionary to a list and iterate over the list of keys.

  ```
  my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

  for key in list(my_dict.keys()):
      print(key)
      if key == 'b':
          del my_dict[key]

  print(my_dict)  # ️ {'a': 1, 'c': 3}
  ```

Comment: This is completely redundant with the original answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can make function and do this

```
    d = {'a': [1], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [], 'd':[]}
    def remove_empty_list(d : dict ) -> dict:
        return {k:v  for k,v in d.items() if  v }
    print(remove_empty_list(d))
```

Answer (score -1):

This approach can be used if the values in the dictionary are also unique:

```
keyToBeDeleted = None
for k, v in mydict.items():
    if(v == match):
        keyToBeDeleted = k
        break
mydict.pop(keyToBeDeleted, None)
```

Comment: There's a useful idea here, but the implementation is specific to a problem that differs from OP's example. It would be better to give a general technique (e.g., show the code with some placeholder for deciding whether an item should be removed, and show code that can remove multiple items) and *explain how* it solves the problem. However, Rohit's answer from 2018 already demonstrates exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

**Nested null values**

Let's say we have a dictionary with nested keys, some of which are null values:

```
dicti = {
"k0_l0":{
    "k0_l1": {
        "k0_l2": {
                "k0_0":None,
                "k1_1":1,
                "k2_2":2.2
                }
        },
        "k1_l1":None,
        "k2_l1":"not none",
        "k3_l1":[]
    },
    "k1_l0":"l0"
}
```

Then we can remove the null values using this function:

```
def pop_nested_nulls(dicti):
    for k in list(dicti):
        if isinstance(dicti[k], dict):
            dicti[k] = pop_nested_nulls(dicti[k])
        elif not dicti[k]:
            dicti.pop(k)
    return dicti
```

Output for `pop_nested_nulls(dicti)`

```
{'k0_l0': {'k0_l1': {'k0_l2': {'k1_1': 1,
                               'k2_2': 2.2}},
           'k2_l1': 'not '
                    'none'},
 'k1_l0': 'l0'}
```

Comment: This is essentially inventing a new problem to solve. The issue in the OP isn't at all specific to "removing nulls"; that's just one of countless examples of processing that would run into the same category of problem. And of course a nested structure can be processed using recursion; that's completely irrelevant to the topic.