# Find highest weight edge(s) for a given node

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I have a directed graph in NetworkX. The edges are weighted from 0 to 1, representing probabilities that they occurred. The network connectivity is quite high, so I want to prune the edges such for every node, only the highest probability node remains.

I'm not sure how to iterate over every node and keep only the highest weighted `in_edges` in the graph. Is there a networkx function that allows us to do this?

Here is an example of what I'd like to be able to do.

```
Nodes:
A, B, C, D

Edges:
A->B, weight=1.0
A->C, weight=1.0
A->D, weight=0.5
B->C, weight=0.9
B->D, weight=0.8
C->D, weight=0.9

Final Result Wanted:
A->B, weight=1.0
A->C, weight=1.0
C->D, weight=0.9
```

If there are two edges into a node, and they are both of the highest weight, I'd like to keep them both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I had was inspired by Aric. I used the following code:

```
for node in G.nodes():
    edges = G.in_edges(node, data=True)
    if len(edges) > 0: #some nodes have zero edges going into it
        min_weight = min([edge[2]['weight'] for edge in edges])
        for edge in edges:
            if edge[2]['weight'] > min_weight:
                G.remove_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
```

Answer (score 8):

Here are some ideas:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('A','B', weight=1.0)
G.add_edge('A','C', weight=1.0)
G.add_edge('A','D', weight=0.5)
G.add_edge('B','C', weight=0.9)
G.add_edge('B','D', weight=0.8)
G.add_edge('C','D', weight=0.9)

print "all edges"
print G.edges(data=True)

print "edges >= 0.9"
print [(u,v,d) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] >= 0.9]

print "sorted by weight"
print sorted(G.edges(data=True), key=lambda (source,target,data): data['weight'])
```

Comment: Aric, your answer is quite close to what I'm looking for, but I'm having trouble with the threshold that you set. I'm not looking for something that's above a certain threshold (`weight >=0.9`). You'll see that B->C is not included, as there is an edge A->C that is weighted higher. Rather, I'm looking for the top-valued edge(s) going into a given node. Perhaps I'll have to edit the question to make this clearer?

Comment: On second look, your answer provided me with the inspiration for what I needed to do. I will post my solution in a moment, but in the meantime, I will up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of ericmjl provided does not work entirely in my program due to the following [Runtime Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error).
Moreover, it keeps the edges with the lowest probability, not the highest, as asked in the question (because: remove all edges with weight > min, instead remove all with weight < max). Furthermore, it sufficient to do the inner loop for len(edges) > 1, because we want to remove all edges from nodes with more than one edge.

The complete solution:

```
for node in G.nodes():
    edges = G.edges(node, data=True)
    if len(edges) > 1:  # some nodes have zero edges going into it
        max_weight = max([edge[2]['weight'] for edge in edges])

        for edge in list(edges):
            if edge[2]['weight'] < max_weight:
                G.remove_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
```