# Why is this code to delete negative values from a dictionary not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have to get rid of all the entries which have negative value. Why is my code not working?

```
dic = {'aa': 20, 'bb': -10, 'cc': -12}

for i in dic:
    if dic[i] < 0:
        del dic[i]
        
print(dic)
```

When running this code I get an exception:

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: you cannot delete an entry in this loop. You can store them into a list or something else.

Comment: But how does that help me in getting rid of those entries from the dictionary?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [How to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using dict comprehensions.

```
dic = {k: v for (k, v) in dic.items() if v >= 0}
```

Comment: +1 but should be `dic.items()` instead of `dic.values()`. Also, there is no need for parentheses around `k` and `v` in `for (k, v) ...`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work in Python 2.x - substituting the for loop with

```
 for i in dic.keys():
   if dic[i]<0:
    del dic[i]
```

The reason why this doesn't work in Python 3.x is that `keys` returns an iterator instead of a list-- I found an explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11941855/2314737

Quite a subtle difference--I didn't know that.

So, in Python 3.x you would need to use

```
for i in list(dic):
```

Comment: Have you checked your indentation?

Answer (score 2):

```
delete_list = []
for i in dic:
    if dic[i] < 0:
        delete_list.append(i)
for each in delete_list:
    del dic[each]
```

Comment: welcome. Just cannot delete an item in a list when you run loop of this list.

Comment: In my opinion, the user2314737's last line solution with `list(dic)` is cleaner in the readability sense. Also copying the wanted items to another dict as shown by Steinar Lina is nice because it loops only once through the dictionary. I suggest to measure all three solutions to know what is the best :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `dict.pop()`:

```
myDict = {'aa': 20, 'bb': -10, 'cc': -12}
condition = []

for x, y in myDict.items ():
    if y <  0:
        condition.append(x)
        
[myDict.pop(x) for x in condition ]

print(myDict)
```

gives

```
{'aa': 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = {}
# ...

keys = list(d.keys())

for key in keys:
  if something_is_true:
    del d[key]
```