# dict changed size during iteration, but not editing it in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm getting the `dict changed size during iteration` error in Python even though I'm not altering the nested dict. I'm deleting from the original, not the copy that I'm looping through

```
test = arr.copy()
for map in test:
    for mID in test[map]:  #here is dictionary changed size during iteration
        v = test[map][mID]['val']
        if v < 1:
            del arr[map][mID]
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: With nested data structures you need to use `copy.deepcopy()` instead of `copy()`

Comment: There's no need to copy the whole dict - just iterate over a copy of the keys (i.e. use `list(test)` and `list(test[map])`).

Comment: @ekhumoro you're right! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're copying the dictionary but using *shallow copy*.

Since you're iterating on a sub-dict (which isn't copied, the reference is the same between `arr` and `test`), you get this error.

Use the `deepcopy` function of the `copy` module like this:

```
import copy
test = copy.deepcopy(arr)
```

However, deep-copying an object is overkill for such a problem. You could just iterate on a copy of the items like this (also: always iterate on key+values so you don't have to access the value by key within the loop):

```
for map,map_values in arr.items():
    for mID,subdict in list(map_values.items()):  # make a copy/force iteration using `list`
        v = subdict['val']
        if v < 1:
            del map_values[mID]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with nested dicts, you should create a deep copy.

```
import copy
test = copy.deepcopy(arr)
```

Note that `copy.copy` and `dict.copy` only create shallow copies!

[Docs for dict.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=copy#dict.copy):

> Return a shallow copy of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are right: `copy()` returns a shallow copy of the dictionary, so `arr[map]` will be a copy of `test[map]`, but `arr[map][mID]` and `arr[map][mID]` will be exactly `test[map][mID]`.

The following schema shows the situation:

```
arr  -+-> 'map1' -+-> { 'id1':{'val':0}, ... }
      |           |
      +-> 'map2' ---+-> { 'id1':{'val':2}, ... }
                  | |
test -+-> 'map1' -+ |
      |             |
      +-> 'map2' ---+
```

When you try to delete `arr['map1']['id1']`, you are also trying to delete `test['map1']['id1']`, yet you are iterating on `test['map1']`. That's why you are getting this error (the size of `test['map1']` may not change while you are iterating on it).

But I don't think that a `deepcopy` is the good solution. All that you need is to copy the keys of `arr[map]` and iterate over this copy.

```
for map in arr:
    for mID in list(arr[map]): # here's the copy of the keys
        v = arr[map][mID]['val']
        if v < 1:
            del arr[map][mID] # allowed because you are not iterating on the dict, but on the copy of the keys
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCoMwEETv/YqBHlKhh2pvob310m8QD8FEXbBRYipY8dvTTaBC57Iw@3Z2xsV3g70G5RzuWMVLjUKugnQex6x6IS/bGWwUu1Fs2xaawYFhkAXfygNYyXs@otfT5E@8KJmpMgkcO@MMaIKm2tNglVtQd8q2RmOij4F@O7ItyBunIpASo2Yu9ksqOb4qU41qB6hh5oZc7k6UNv3/WRj5QSqVhS8)

Some reading: [How to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error)