# Python: What is the source of this RuntimeError when checking imported modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

### What I Want to Do:

Check the different modules I've imported in my script (Python 2 or 3), and print their names. I'm currently using Python 2.7.12 and 3.6.4.

### Where I Started:

The script simply imports modules, uses list comprehension to find what's there, and prints a list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import types

module_list = [i.__name__ for i in globals().values()
               if type(i) == types.ModuleType and i in sys.modules.values()]
print(module_list)
```

I was initially running this in Python 3, and it works just fine (also fine for Python 2). The output is:

```
['__builtin__', 'sys', 'os', 'types']  # Python 2.
['builtins', 'sys', 'os', 'types']     # Python 3.
```

At this point, I decided to expand the list comprehension out, as I find it to be good practice in deciphering code/logical flow. So I replaced the single statement with:

```
module_list = []
for i in globals().values():
    if type(i) == types.ModuleType and i in sys.modules.values():
        module_list.append(i.__name__)
```

Here's where things get hairy. I get a `RuntimeError`, and the output is now:

```
...
    for i in globals().values():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

However, **it still works in Python 2**. I'm now more curious than anything else, and tried a few things.

### What I Tried:

- Turned `globals().values()` into a list:

  ```
  for i in list(globals().values()):
      if type(i) == types.ModuleType and i in sys.modules.values():
          module_list.append(i.__name__)
  ```

  This works as intended in Python 2 or 3.
- Removed the `list()` and added in proper `main` structure:

  ```
  def main():
      module_list = []
      for i in globals().values():
          if type(i) == type(sys) and i in sys.modules.values():
              module_list.append(i.__name__)
      print(module_list)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```

  This works as intended in Python 2 and 3.

### To Recap:

- List comprehension works for Python 2 and 3.
- The `for` loop only works for Python 2.
- Wrapping in a `list` works for Python 2 and 3.
- Proper `main` structuring works for Python 2 and 3.

### The Question:

What is it about that `for` loop in Python 3 that's breaking things?

Comment: This may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11941817/8146556     Also a good article on this topic here: https://cito.github.io/blog/never-iterate-a-changing-dict/

Answer (score 1):

`for i in globals().values():` - `i` is added to the global namespace after you get the `values` iterator. If you put `i = None` before the loop, or do `for i in list(globals().values()):`, it works.

In python 2, `values()` returns a list of values, but in python 3 its an iterator. That iterator detects the change and raises the error.