# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Have a dictionary which has a list of dictionaries which will be altered but getting the error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

This was working with python2 but not with python3. How to make it work with python3?

```
multi_van_data = {'Van1': [{'ClusterStops': [], 'OptimalStop': 'GSV07858'},
                           {'ClusterStops': [], 'OptimalStop': 'GSV07932'},             
                           {'ClusterStops': [], 'OptimalStop': 'GSV07903'},
                           {'OptimalStop': 'GSV07892', 'ClusterStops': ['GSV07903']}]}

for k, v in multi_van_data.items():
    for val in v:
        val['ParentSequence'] = route.index(val['OptimalStop']) + 1
        val['ParentServiceTime'] = 1
        val['ParkstopTravelTime'] = 1
        val['ApproxCompletionTime'] = []
        cluster_stops = val['ClusterStops']
        print cluster_stops
        val.pop('ClusterStops')
```

Want to remove all ClusterStops

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, seems like it worked. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why did it fail before? The duplicate question shows the dictionary being modified, but OP here doesn't modify the dictionary.

Comment: because `items()` returned a copy of the items in python 2. So no need to convert to `list`. So, yes, OP is modifying the dictionary right now when using python 3.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre which line of code first modifies the dictionary?

Comment: none, actually. Code works fine, my bad. But print without parentheses suggests that this hasn't been run with python 3. And `route` isn't defined, which means that this isn't a [mcve]. Reopening but will recommend "cannot reproduce" (damn I shouldn't have reopened, OP commented that my suggestion fixed the issue!!!). Well that's a mess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11941817/608639)