# How to remove k,v entries from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to remove the values I don't need from an existing json file:

```
{ "items": [ { "id": "abcd", "h": 2, "x": 0, "level": 4 }, { "id": "dfgg", "h": 7, "x": 5, "level": 30 } ] }
```

I've tried to remove the values in place but get 'dictionary changed size during iteration'.

```
with open('inventory2.json', 'r') as inf:
    data = json.load(inf)
    inf.close()

    keysiwant = ['x', 'h']
    for dic in data['items']:
        for k, v in dic.items():
            if k not in keysiwant:
                dic.pop(k, None)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: `dict.items()` in python 3 is just a *view* - not a copy of the dict's items - you cannot change it while iterating.

You can however put the `dict.items()` iterator into a `list()` (which copies it and decouples it from the dict that way) - you can then iterate over the copy of the `dict.items()` instead:

```
import json

t = """{ "items": [ { "id": "abcd", "h": 2, "x": 0, "level": 4 }, 
                    { "id": "dfgg", "h": 7, "x": 5, "level": 30 } ] }"""

data = json.loads(t)   # loads is better for SO-examples .. it makes it a mcve
keysiwant = ['x', 'h']
for dic in data['items']:
    for k, v in list(dic.items()):
        if k not in keysiwant:
            dic.pop(k, None)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'items': [{'h': 2, 'x': 0}, {'h': 7, 'x': 5}]}
```

More on python2/python3 `dict.items()`: [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39432100/7505395) to [What is the difference between dict.items() and dict.iteritems()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)

Comment: json.loads() gave an error, still used json.load(), otherwise, nailed it thank you :)

Comment: @Scott `json.loads()` is to load json from a _`string`_ not a file ;) hence better for demonstration as [mcve] on SO

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It uses fewer iterations because it filters out keys first, before sending them to pop/remove. Also, it uses keys only (list(dic)) instead of tuple key/value.

```
import json

t = """{ "items": [ { "id": "abcd", "h": 2, "x": 0, "level": 4 },
                    { "id": "dfgg", "h": 7, "x": 5, "level": 30 } ] }"""

data = json.loads(t)
keysiwant = ["x", "h"]

for dic in data["items"]:
    for k in (k for k in list(dic) if k not in keysiwant):
        dic.pop(k, None)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'items': [{'h': 2, 'x': 0}, {'h': 7, 'x': 5}]}
```

Comment: Works just as well maybe slightly faster on the few comparisons I ran. Thank you!