# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration - how to solve?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to traverse through a dictionary and capitalize all of the keys if they are strings.  I am getting a RunTime error for this:

```
for k, v in ref_dict.items():
    if isinstance(k, str):
        ref_dict[k.upper()] = v
    else:
        ref_dict[k] = v
```

How do I avoid something like this? Or, better, how do I improve the code in order to solve this more elegantly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is your dict? If it is not huge, then you could do:

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in ref_dict.items():
    if isinstance(k, str):
        new_dict[k.upper()] = v
    else:
        new_dict[k] = v

ref_dict = new_dict
```

In the other case, you may need to review your creation of `ref_dict` and modify the key there.

Also, one could modify your original code as follows change `ref_dict`. But it's worth mentioning that it would add new elements to `ref_dict`. For example

```
ref_dict = {'abc' : 1}

### change of code
keys = [k for key in ref_dict]

for k in keys:
    if isinstance(k, str):
        ref_dict[k.upper()] = ref_dict[k]
    # else part is not neccessary
    # else:
    #     ref_dict[k] = v

# now ref_dict = {'abc':1, 'ABC':1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this:

```
final_dict = dict((str(k).upper(), v) for k, v in ref_dict.items())
return final_dict
```

The `str` application is not ideal, but it will do for now.

Comment: This is essentially my suggestion in better python style. You can do `final_dict = dict((k.upper(), v) if isinstance(k, str) else (k,v) for k, v in ref_dict.items())`.

Comment: @QuangHoang beautiful. This is perfect! Thanks a bunch.