# Python dictionaries are not allowed to change size but lists are?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I think I just found a gotcha in Python.

Take a look at the following code:

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

for i in a.values():
    if i == 2:
        a['d'] = 4
        
print(a)
```

This will result in a RuntimeError of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I come from a Java background **so this makes sense that you can't actually modify data structures while you are iterating over them.**

But this logic falls apart when you see the following code work fine for lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

for i in iter(a):
    if i == 2:
        a.extend([5,6,7])
        
print(a)
```

The code outputs as expected:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

**Why does this work for lists but fail for dictionaries ?**

This makes no sense.

I know that `dict.values()`, `dict.items()`, `dict.keys()` all return iterators **BUT SO DO LISTS.**

This code is using an iterator, right ?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

for i in iter(a):
    if i == 2:
        a.extend([5,6,7])
        
print(a)
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

I did check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11941855/7134737) but I failed to get a concrete answer.

**Why the special treatment for dictionaries?**

Am I missing something very basic here?

Comment: `for x in a` is not an iterator, and any of these is not a part of the standard. In other implementations of Python you might get different results

Comment: @Marat Check my code now. I am specifically using an iterator with a list.

Comment: @Marat What do you mean, it's not a iterator?

Comment: the second part still holds, it is an undefined behavior. It is not an intentional part of the language design

Comment: @Marat So all this is unintentional ? Nothing described here is standard ? That doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: correct. It is just an implementation side effect

Comment: "I know that dict.values(), dict.items(), dict.keys() all return iterators...." No, technically [they return views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

Comment: FWIW, `iter(a)` is not needed to reproduce the same behaviour.

Comment: @wjandrea FWIW, My original question did not contain it. I added it after Marat said lists don't return iterators.

Comment: I believe that both Python and Java frown on the modification of iterated-over containers, but that neither language *guarantees* that it will be detected. However, the marginal is too narrow to fit... er, I mean I can't find this in the docs for either language right now, and it's bedtime here. :)

Comment: @TurePålsson Excatly. I even skimmed over the PEP for the iterators and couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: `a.values()` returns an iterable in Python3, not an iterator. By calling `iter(a)`, you're returning an iterable which is not allowed to change size.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily avoid this by doing this

```
a = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
for i in list(a.values()):
    if i == 2:
        a['d'] = 4
print(a)
```

As for why the different treatment I don't know, by but as long as you're not iterating through the dictionary itself it will work

Comment: I don't want to avoid it. I want to know why it is happening. I don't want a work-around I want a reason. The language design is inconsistent otherwise.

Comment: @ng.newbie inconsistent language design is hardly unique to Python.  I suspect the reason is that an iterator into a `dict` is tightly bound to the internal structure of that dict, and can't handle updates in real time.  There's really nothing wrong with a work-around.

Comment: @MarkRansom Fully agree there is nothing wrong with the work-around but there has to be a concrete reason for this. Or else updates while iterating should be disabled on lists as well.

Comment: @MarkRansom I suspect it's because dicts used to be unordered. I can't imagine adding/deleting items while iterating an unordered collection, that would be unpredictable/unreliable. But for lists I've done that many times (mostly appending).

Comment: I think @Stefan Pochmann is right however, if you're looking for good evidence of this I recommend checking other versions of python and see how they differ in this like IronPython *C# based* or Jython *java based* instead of CPython, or just check the source code of one of these versions and check for supposed errors in the dict class; here is the Cpython source code https://github.com/python/cpython

and here's Jython's  
https://github.com/jython hope it helps

Comment: @StefanPochmann Wait, aren't lists also unordered ? I have seen no explicit ordering imposed on lists. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @ng.newbie I think this is the most use full for your case https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c

Comment: @ng.newbie only sets and dicts are unordered however lists and tuples are ordered

Comment: @ng.newbie Lists unordered? I hope you're joking :-)

Answer (score -1):

You have it backwards.  The special treatment is not for dictionaries, the special treatment is for lists.  That's because it's trivial to iterate through a changing list - you keep an integer that tells you the offset into the list.  Every time you try to access an item through the iterator, you can check to see that it's still within the bounds of the list and generate an exception if it isn't.

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> x = 2
>>> for i in a:
    print(i)
    if x < 10:
        a[0:0] = [x]
        x += 1

1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
>>> a
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I do see special treatment for dictionaries [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0dd98c2d00a75efbec19c2ed942923981bc06683/Objects/dictobject.c#L3743-L3748). What/where is the special treatment for lists?

Comment: @StefanPochmann what I meant by that was the general prohibition on modifying a sequence that you're iterating.  That's the base case and anything that deviates from it is special.  Obviously the construction of the data structure is going to dictate the mechanics of how you iterate it, so will require custom code.