# Graph dictionary outputs RuntimeError

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, graph

I have a dictionary of lists:

```py
g = {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'd', 'e']}
```

in which some of the values are not present as keys. I want to add all values, as keys with empty lists, which are not present in keys. Current I am attempting to do this as follows:

```py
for keys, values in g.items():
    for value in values:
        if value not in keys:
            g[value] = []
```

Running the above code gives a traceback: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. I checked other related questions in Stackoverflow but couldn't find a related task.

I look to have the following output:

```py
{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'd', 'e'], 'c': [], 'd': [], 'e': []}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
g = {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'd', 'e']}

for keys, values in list(g.items()):
    for value in values:
        if value not in g:
            g[value] = []

print(g)
```

#### Explanation

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error) Stack Overflow post for more information regarding using `list()`. Also, your conditional should check if `value` is in `g`, not in `keys`.