# how to assign key and value of dictionary to different variables iteratively in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have this dictionary

```
myDict = {'key1' : 'val1', 'key2' : 'val2', 'key3' : 'val3'}
```

and I am iteratively using 'key' and 'value' of 'myDict' to create check and radio buttons.

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
    myDict[key] = Variable()
    myDict[value] = Variable()
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=key, variable=myDict[key], onvalue=key, offvalue="").pack(anchor=W)
    
    Radiobutton(root, text='radio1', variable=myDict[value], value=1).pack(anchor=E)
    Radiobutton(root, text='radio2', variable=myDict[value], value=2).pack(anchor=E)

    var_list.append(myDict[key]) #var_list is an empty list defined already
print(var_list)
```

and I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Check_box_lis_0305.py", line 21, in <module>
for key, value in myDict.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Could you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Did this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error ?

Comment: Neither of the comments here are helpful. You need to store the `Variable` values in a separate spot.  Remember, that's where tkinter will store the result of the check or radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
checks = {}
radios = {}
for key, value in myDict.items():
    checks[key] = Variable()
    radios[key] = Variable()
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=key, variable=checks[key], onvalue=key, offvalue="").pack(anchor=W)
    
    Radiobutton(root, text='radio1', variable=radios[key], value=1).pack(anchor=E)
    Radiobutton(root, text='radio2', variable=radios[key], value=2).pack(anchor=E)

    var_list.append(checks[key]) #var_list is an empty list defined already
print(var_list)
```

Now, when you get a click event, `checks[key]` will have the value of the check button, and `radios[key]` will have the selection for the radio button.  I'm not sure why you need `var_list` here.

Comment: I used `radios[value]` instead of `radios[key]`, does that make sense?

Comment: my bigger task here is to create 3 lists.  `def add_to_list():    listA = []    listD = []    listC = []    for i in var_list:    if i.get() != "":    listA.append(i.get())    if radios[value].get() == 1:    listD.append(i.get())    else:    listC.append(i.get())    print(listA)    print(listD)    print(listC)    Button(root, text='OK', command=add_to_list).pack(anchor=W)`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, here the idea is to add all checked buttons to `listA` and for all the checked buttons add the key to `listD` if `radios[value]==1` and to `listC` otherwise. However the list being assigned to either `listD` or `listC` based on the radio selection of last key in the list(last loop key). Sorry if I confused you

Comment: Don't type big chunks of code in comments.  Add an update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the dictionary during the for loop with

```
myDict[key] = Variable()
myDict[value] = Variable()
```

Comment: And what should he do to fix that?