# I want to update the dictionary. But its generating , RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```py
dic1={"God Arises":"Ali","Mysterious":"sherry"}
name= input("Enter Your Name: ")

bookNam =input("Enter book name that you want to lend: ")
for key1 in dic1:
        if key1==bookNam:
            print("Book Not available")
        else:
            dic1.update({bookNam:name})
```

Comment: You are right it works but if i want to use for loop then what can i do, i have used it in this way but its also executing the else part every time whether condition is true or false.......................................................................   'name2= input("Enter Your Name: ")
      
        bookNam = input("Enter book name that you want to lend: ")

        for key1 in list(dic1.keys()):
            if key1 == bookNam:
                print(f"Book Not available")

            else:
                  dic1.update({bookNam:name2})'

Comment: Welcome to SO, please comment in the answer section not in the question itself. I have updated the answer to address what you are observing with the for loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use for-loop to check if key is in the dictionary. Use `in` operator. For example:

```py
dic1 = {"God Arises": "Ali", "Mysterious": "sherry"}
name = input("Enter Your Name: ")

bookNam = input("Enter book name that you want to lend: ")
if bookNam in dic1:
    print("Book Not available")
else:
    dic1.update({bookNam: name})
```

Comment: `dic1.update({bookNam: name})` -> `dic1[bookNam] = name`

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop through your dictionary.

You can either use `bookNam in dict1.keys()`

You can also use `dic1.get(bookNam) is not None`

Or a perfectly pythonic way by trying to access the key and catch the exception

```
try:
    print(f"Book '{dic1[bookNam]}' Not available")
except KeyError:
    dic1.update({bookNam: name})
```

If you really need to loop through a dictionary and add/remove items, I would suggest to make a copy of the keys and loop through those ones instead.

In your case it would work if you used this:

```
for key1 in list(dic1.keys()):
    if key1 == bookNam:
        print("Book Not available")
        break
 else:
     dic1.update({bookNam:name})
```

Comment: `dic1.update({bookNam: name})` -> `dic1[bookNam] = name`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga unless you are really looping through millions of entries (which is not the case here). I think update vs assignment is a preference choice.