# How to change the key in dictionary by its value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am unsure if a dictionary can have values without keys, but am trying to learn more about dictionaries in python. I created a dictionary as follows:

```
dict={'Type': 'Electric_car', 'Make': 'Tesla', 'Model': 'S', 'Year': 2020, 'Price': 21000, '': 22.2}
```

I want to update the blank key in the dictionary to `"Power":22.2`
This is how I tried, which is obviously wrong.

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    if value==22.2:
        dict[key]=dict["Power"]
```

Is there any way to update the key by using the value?

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but `22.2 != 22.22`

Comment: You might need this next: [How to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11941817/4518341)

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions. The examples show how to update to new key by popping the old key. I want to know if we can update the key only if its value is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, though i'm sure it's not the most efficient route:

```
dict={'Type': 'Electric_car', 'Make': 'Tesla', 'Model': 'S', 'Year': 2020, 'Price': 21000, '': 22.2}

for key, value in list(dict.items()):
    if value == 22.2:
        dict["power"] = dict.pop(key)
```

Output:

```
{'Type': 'Electric_car', 'Make': 'Tesla', 'Model': 'S', 'Year': 2020, 'Price': 21000, 'power': 22.2}
```

Comment: Didn't work. But I understood what you tried to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like `d['Power'] = d.pop('')`. Example:

```py
>>> d = {'Type': 'Electric_car', 'Make': 'Tesla', 'Model': 'S', 'Year': 2020, 'Price': 21000, '': 22.2}
>>> d['Power'] = d.pop('')
>>> d
{'Type': 'Electric_car', 'Make': 'Tesla', 'Model': 'S', 'Year': 2020, 'Price': 21000, 'Power': 22.2}
```

However, it's fishy that you would be using the empty string as a key. You should try to not get yourself into that situation in the first place.

Comment: Where's the loop? OP wants to change the key based on the value, which requires a loop.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes! I want to know if we can change the key by its value, incase if I know just the value and not the key. Apologies, if it doesn't make sense. I want to understand the concept here.

Comment: You could do that with a loop like the example you showed (though as someone pointed out, there's a typo between 22.2 versus 22.22, and you probably need a `break` statement as well). However, it's generally a bad idea to put yourself in such a situation. Based on the example data, I would guess that 22.2 would never show up as the value of `Type` or `Year`, so you should format your data from the start in such a way that these don't have to be searched through.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to "update" a key.  The best you can do is re-insert with the new key, then delete the old key.