# python recursion to remove dict keys

Tags: python-3.x

i want to remove empty dict from nested dict and list dict

```
input = {'a':'sd','b':{'c':'fd','f':{},'d':'sdsd','j':[{'a':'gg'},{'a':'oio'},{'a':{}}]},'h':''}

def recurfun(dict_data):
    for key,values in ss.items():
        if isinstance(values, dict) and values == {}:
            del ss[key]
        if isinstance(values, dict):
            recurfun(values)
    return ss
recurfun(ss)
```

error message is "dictionary changed size during iteration"

```
output_should_be = {"a":"12","b":{"f":"34"}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941817/how-to-avoid-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting keys in-place, you can build a new dict using a dict comprehension with an `if` clause to filter out values of an empty dict:

```
def recurfun(d):
    return {k: recurfun(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for k, v in d.items() if v != {}}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/SelfreliantWonderfulBlogware

Comment: Will it work if dict is under list ?