# Python delete items from dictionary who's value fit a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Naivelly I would use:

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    if foo(v):
        del dictionary[k]
```

However this will cause an iterator exception as I edit the dictionary size while iterating over it. So how could I do this? - and especially, **without making a copy of the dictionary**, the copy approach:

```
copydict = dict(dictionary)
for k, v in copydict.items():
    if foo(v):
        del dictionary[k]
```

I wish to see how python would do such in place editing without actually using explicit iterators.

Comment: As an aside... `copydict = dictionary.copy()` is preferred... (it has its own `.copy` for a reason)

Comment: Why again the downvoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all the keys to remove then delete after:

```
d = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
remove = [k for k  in d if foo(d[k])]
for k in remove:
    del d[k]


In [38]: %%timeit
   ....: d = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
   ....: matching_items = ((k, v) for k, v in list(d.items()) if v > 2)
   ....: d.clear()
   ....: d.update(matching_items)
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.85 µs per loop

In [40]: %%timeit
        d = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
        remove =[k for k  in d if d[k]> 2]
        for k in remove:
           del d[k]
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 873 ns per loop
```

Comment: I suspected mine was a bad idea, but you'd already nicked the good idea... was experimenting... thanks for the timeit's - have a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer from a previous Stack Overflow question: [Modifying a Python dict while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/modifying-a-python-dict-while-iterating-over-it)

`dictionary.items()` returns a view which can't be modified
But if you iterate over `list(dictionary.items())` you can modify the dictionary without the risk of iterator exception.

Comment: All links in that answer lead to python 2.x.. In python 3 iteritems deprecated, and items() was changed to act like iteritems (from what I understand). So is this advice still true for 3.3?

Comment: items is an iterator in python 3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Don't you mean this answer is incorrect then for python 3?

Comment: you are right: here is the python 3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

Comment: @paul23,yes you cannot iterate over dict.items in python 3 and delete a key

Comment: it works if you cast `dict.items()` to a list as such: `list(dict.items())` -- changed the answer code.

Comment: still won't work, you cannot iterate over and change the dict

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in dictionary.viewkeys():
     if f(dictionary[k]):
         del dictionary[k]
```

Comment: viewitems doesn't allocate memory for an actual copy?

Comment: In fact only keys are needed, so viewkeys is suffice.

Comment: again I guess this is for python 2.x? And not working with python's 3.x's new view objects?

Comment: @paul23 you just use `.keys()` in 3.x