# for loop skipping sections of dictionary in python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

```
GeoFigs =  {'Populus':0, 'Tristidia':1, 'Albus':2, 'Fortuna Major':3, 'Rubeus':4,
            'Acquisitio':5, 'Conjunctivo':6, 'Caput Draconis':7, 'Laetita':8, 'Carcer':9, 
            'Amissio':10, 'Puella':11, 'Fortuna Minor':12, 'Puer':13, 'Cauda Draconis':14, 'Via':15}
KeyGeo = dict.copy(GeoFigs)
for key in KeyGeo:
    print KeyGeo[key]
    keychange = KeyGeo[key]
    newValue = key
    del KeyGeo[key]
    KeyGeo[keychange] =  newValue
```

When I run the for loop it skips over some of the keys producing

```
(0, 'Populus'), (1, 'Tristidia'), ('Carcer', 9), (3, 'Fortuna Major'), (4, 'Rubeus'),
(5, 'Acquisitio'), (6, 'Conjunctivo'), (7, 'Caput Draconis'), ('Puer', 13), (10, 'Amissio'),
(11, 'Puella'), (12, 'Fortuna Minor'), (2, 'Albus'), (14, 'Cauda Draconis'), (15, 'Via'), ('Laetita', 8)]
```

Any idea why it's skipping the 3rd and the 9th only?

Comment: Dictionaries are normally hash based implementations. So, the order in which the values are stored may not be the same always.

Comment: You are deleting elements from a collection as you iterate it. Don't do this. Never.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues at play here:

1. The ordering of keys in a `dict` is not defined. If you care about the ordering, using something like [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).
2. You are making structural changes to the `dict` while iterating over it. See [Modifying a Python dict while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/modifying-a-python-dict-while-iterating-over-it)

Answer (score 0):

Others have nailed the problem - you are changing the dict as you iterate. You solve the problem by getting a copy of the keys before you start. Its a bit different in python 2 and 3. In python 2, `keys` is a list:

```
for key in KeyGeo.keys():
    ...
```

In python 3, `keys` is an iterator so you have to iterate before you start

```
for key in list(KeyGeo.keys()):
    ...
```