# reversing dictionary in python doesn't work

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a code for switching between the key and value in a dictionary:

```
for k in d:
    d[d[k]] = k
    d.pop(k)
```

The problem with this code that it makes more operations that it should make, and for some inputs return the wrong result

what is the reason of this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying a Python dict while iterating over it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/modifying-a-python-dict-while-iterating-over-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the dictionary while iterating over it, and who knows what problems that causes.

Note that generally speaking you can't reverse dictionaries: keys must be unique and hashable, but values don't have to be. I'm assuming your dictionaries have unique hashable values so that it's at least possible.

Then I would use a dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary, and assign that:

```
d = {value: key for (key, value) in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding values to a dictionary as you are iterating through it.  Generally this is a bad idea.  It is better to construct a new dictionary using dictionary comprehension.

```
new_d = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}
```