# Update dictionary key inside list using map function -Python

Tags: dictionary, map-function

I have a dictionary of phone numbers where number is Key and country is value. I want to update the key and add country code based on value country. I tried to use the map function for this:

```
print('**Exmaple: Update phone book to add Country code using map function** ')
user=[{'952-201-3787':'US'},{'952-201-5984':'US'},{'9871299':'BD'},{'01632 960513':'UK'}]

#A function that takes a dictionary as arg, not list. List is the outer part
def add_Country_Code(aDict):
            for k,v in aDict.items():
                if(v == 'US'):
                 aDict[( '1+'+k)]=aDict.pop(k)
                if(v == 'UK'):
                 aDict[( '044+'+k)]=aDict.pop(k)
                if (v == 'BD'):
                 aDict[('001+'+k)] =aDict.pop(k)
            return aDict

new_user=list(map(add_Country_Code,user))

print(new_user)
```

This works partially when I run, output below  :
[{'1+952-201-3787': 'US'}, {'1+1+1+952-201-5984': 'US'}, {'001+9871299': 'BD'}, {'044+01632 960513': 'UK'}]

Notice the 2nd US number has 2 additional 1s'. What is causing that?How to fix? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue**

You are [mutating a dict while iterating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/modifying-a-python-dict-while-iterating-over-it).  Don't do this.  The Pythonic convention would be:

1. Make a `new_dict = {}`
2. While iterating the input `a_dict`, assign new items to `new_dict`.
3. Return the `new_dict`

IOW, *create new things*, rather than *change old things* - likely the source of your woes.

**Some notes**

- Use lowercase with underscores when defining variable names (see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)).
- Lookup values rather than change the input dict, e.g. `a_dict[k]` vs. `a_dict.pop(k)`
- Indent the correct number of spaces (see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation))