# Replace character when reading a file CSV

Tags: python

I want to replace all character(',') with character ('.')

I try with this code :

```
spamReader = csv.DictReader(base64.b64decode(self.file_name).decode('utf-8').split('\n'), delimiter=';')
    for row in reversed(list(spamReader)):
         for k, v in row.items():
         row[k] = k.replace(',', '.')
```

But , does not work . Any help please ?

Comment: Is your code formatted as you show it in the question?

Comment: "Does not work" does not provide enough information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why are you using DictReader?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  Your posted code fails on a syntax errror in the last line, and then fails for undefined variables.  Replace the first line with a simple, hard-coded sample of your data structure.  Add `print` statements to display the result.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things here:

1. Your base64 encoding part for the file reference looks a bit strange to me, but if it opens correctly, it shouldn't be the issue here, I guess.
2. You are modifying an object you are iterating over at the same time. I think you should avoid that, since it might lead to strange behaviour, if it works at all. ([Modifying a Python dict while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/modifying-a-python-dict-while-iterating-over-it)).
   It might be a better idea, to simply store your data in a new object.

I tried to fix both in this code and since I am unsure what data structure fits best for your further program, chose something that you should be able to use pretty similar to the OrderedDict that was returned by DictReader:

```
new_data = []
with open('test.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        new_row = []
        for key in row:
            entry = (key, row[key].replace(',','.'))
            new_row.append(entry)
        new_data.append(new_row)
```

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your last line isn't indented properly - it needs 4 more spaces.

Also, I think you're replacing row[k] with a modified k; you may have intended row[k] to be replaced with a modified v.