# Python dictionary not traversing through all elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

below is my python script which needs to traverse all the physical disks which are having logical-paths as well as direct disks

and if we found any logical_paths then we get corresponding physical disk then we remove the logical-part and add the physical-disk corresponding to it into the check dictionary

```
check={
        "/dev/disks/DISK2": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK4": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK5": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK1": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK6": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK3": "",
        "/dev/sda": "/dev/sda"

}
logical_paths={
        "/dev/disks/DISK2": "/ dev / sdc1",
        "/dev/disks/DISK4": "/ dev / sdd2",
        "/dev/disks/DISK5": "/ dev / sde1",
       "/dev/disks/DISK1": "/dev/sdb4"
}
for a in check.keys():
     print("*****")
     print("disk is:"+a)
     if a in logical_paths:
         check[logical_paths[a]]=check[a]
         check.pop(a,None)
print("####")
print(check)
```

But output of my script is:

```
*****
disk is:/dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK2
*****
disk is:/dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK4
*****
disk is:/dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK5
*****
disk is:/dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK1
*****
disk is:/ dev / sdc1
*****
disk is:/ dev / sdd2
*****
disk is:/ dev / sde1
*****
disk is:/dev/sdb4
```

Why is it traversing the disk6,disk3 and SDA

Comment: what you try to archive?

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a `list` from your keys and then iterate above the created list of keys.

## Background

Your problem is that you modify your `dict` while iterating over it. This results into changes of the underlying structure. If you want to see this explicitly, you can comment out the `check.pop(a)` and then you will get an error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. In short, you should avoid modifying the keys of a `dict` while iterating over them. For an extended explanation of your problem see: [Modifying a Python dict while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/modifying-a-python-dict-while-iterating-over-it)

## Fixed code

```
check={
        "/dev/disks/DISK2": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK4": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK5": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK1": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK6": "",
        "/dev/disks/DISK3": "",
        "/dev/sda": "/dev/sda"

}
logical_paths={
        "/dev/disks/DISK2": "/ dev / sdc1",
        "/dev/disks/DISK4": "/ dev / sdd2",
        "/dev/disks/DISK5": "/ dev / sde1",
       "/dev/disks/DISK1": "/dev/sdb4"
}
for a in list(check):
     print("*****")
     print("disk is:"+a)
     if a in logical_paths:
         check[logical_paths[a]]=check[a]
         check.pop(a)
print("####")
print(check)
```

output:

```
*****
disk is:/dev/disks/DISK2
*****
disk is:/dev/disks/DISK4
*****
disk is:/dev/disks/DISK5
*****
disk is:/dev/disks/DISK1
*****
disk is:/dev/disks/DISK6
*****
disk is:/dev/disks/DISK3
*****
disk is:/dev/sda
####
{'/dev/disks/DISK6': '', '/dev/disks/DISK3': '', '/dev/sda': '/dev/sda', '/ dev / sdc1': '', '/ dev / sdd2': '', '/ dev / sde1': '', '/dev/sdb4': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should not remove items from a list/dictionary while iterate through it. So you should better not apply .pop to either list or dict!
I made a simple change in your code:

```
for a in check.keys():
     print("*****")
     print("disk is:",a)
     if a in logical_paths:
         check[a]=logical_paths[a]
       #  check.pop(a,None)
print("####")
print(check)
```

Hope that it generates the correct output for you! The output is:

```
*****
disk is: /dev/disks/DISK2
*****
disk is: /dev/disks/DISK4
*****
disk is: /dev/disks/DISK5
*****
disk is: /dev/disks/DISK1
*****
disk is: /dev/disks/DISK6
*****
disk is: /dev/disks/DISK3
*****
disk is: /dev/sda
####
{'/dev/disks/DISK2': '/ dev / sdc1', '/dev/disks/DISK4': '/ dev / sdd2', '/dev/disks/DISK5': '/ dev / sde1', '/dev/disks/DISK1': '/dev/sdb4', '/dev/disks/DISK6': '', '/dev/disks/DISK3': '', '/dev/sda': '/dev/sda'}
```