Why is this simple Python code resulting in an empty dict?
Why is this simple Python code resulting in an empty dict?
from collections import defaultdict
dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict1['old_key'] = [{'name': 'A'}]
dict1['old_key'].extend(dict1.pop('old_key'))

print(dict1)

My understanding of how this should have worked:
The pop method will return the list associated with the old_key which will be passed to the extend method.
The extend method will set the old_key again; since it won't exist by now, it will initialize it with an empty list and extend that empty list with the list received from the pop method.
So this should have resulted in {'old_key': [{'name': 'A'}]}, but what I am getting is: {}
Context of the actual code:
In my actual code, I need to change the key of the dict, so I am popping the value of the old key and extending the new key with those values.
However, sometimes, it so happens that the new key that is generated based on some conditions is same as the old key, and the code having the extend and pop in same line is behaving weird.
Of course, I can fix it either by splitting into 2 lines: pop first and store the result in a value, and then extend.
Or, before setting new key, I can check if the new key is already in the dict or same as the key being popped.
But I want to understand what is causing the weird behaviour of the code.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777485/modifying-a-python-dict-while-iterating-over-it

TLDR; I think the following is the simplest way to explain what's going on:
temp1 = dict1["old_key"]
temp2 = dict1.pop("old_key")
temp1.extend(temp2)
print(dict1)


Going over the bytecode and keeping in mind what's currently on the stack is how to decipher the dis.dis output.
1: The dict1["old_key"] is first simplified to the value it points to, which is the list created initially:
2 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict1)
4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('old_key')
6 BINARY_SUBSCR
The interpreter stack will at this point look something like this:

<builtins.list object at 0x1234>

2: Then the extend attribute is looked up:
10 LOAD_ATTR                3 (NULL|self + extend)
stack:

<built-in method extend of list object at 0x1234>

3: Load the dict then get the pop attr. and also load the value "old_key".
30 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict1)
32 LOAD_ATTR                5 (NULL|self + pop)
52 LOAD_CONST               0 ('old_key')
<built-in method extend of list object at 0x1234>
<built-in method pop of collections.defaultdict object at 0x4321>
"old_key"
4: call pop ("old_key" is removed from <dict at 4321>, and <list at 1234> is returned)
54 CALL                     1

<built-in method extend of list object at 0x1234>
<builtins.list object at 0x1234>


5: call extend (<list at 1234> is modified in-place by extend method (no return value pushed onto stack))
62 CALL                     1

 



The pop method will return the list associated with the old_key which will be passed to the extend method. The extend method will set the old_key again; since it won't exist by now, it will initialize it with an empty list and extend that empty list with the list received from the pop method.

That's not how the code execute. Python generally executes strictly left to right, so the order of evaluation is:

load dict1
get item 'old_key'
get attribute extend
load dict1
get attribute pop
call pop
call extend

So extend is running on the dict['old_key'] which was subsequently popped from the dict, creating a cyclic list which is then dropped on the ground. Essentially your code does this:
f = dict1['old_key'].extend
f(dict1.pop('old_key'))

Do you see now why it doesn't work?
You can confirm it by decompiling the code via dis:
>>> dis.dis("dict1['old_key'].extend(dict1.pop('old_key'))")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('old_key')
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 LOAD_ATTR                3 (NULL|self + extend)
             30 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict1)
             32 LOAD_ATTR                5 (NULL|self + pop)
             52 LOAD_CONST               0 ('old_key')
             54 CALL                     1
             62 CALL                     1
             70 RETURN_VALUE


In your sequence, pop is called before extend. And extend requires the result of the pop, because that is being passed as a parameter. So the key value should have got set. I do not understand the output of dis and have never used it.

Can you explain what do you mean by: "So extend is running on the dict['old_key'] which was subsequently popped from the dict, creating a cyclic list which is then dropped on the ground". What is dropped and on what ground?

By the time, dict["old_key"] is being set with the new value, if the key no longer exists in the dict because of the pop, should it not have resulted in an exception?

dict1['old_key'] resolves to a list which is not assigned to any variable. Then you pop the key which deletes the key from the dict and returns another instance of the same list. then you call the extend method on the first instance of the list and pass in the second instance of the list. The dict key has been popped however and you are left with no reference to the list so it will be garbage collected.

Great explanation! I think your example could be clearer if the breakdown looked more like: tmp = dict1['old_key']; tmp.extend(dict1.pop('old_key'))

@Aaron, the dict1['old_key'].extend operation is not completed until the key value is set and reassigned, so if the key is popped by that time, it should have thrown an Exception

@Aaron Ok, on rethink, I think your explanation makes sense, because the extend operation is indeed complete. Its just that we now have no way of referencing the list which got extended. Can you please post this as the answer, so I can accept it

@AllSolutions there is no "setting and reassigning" anywhere, extend will update the list in place. And since the pop executes between fetching the list and extending it, the list being extended is removed from the dict, thus the dict ends up empty. dict1['old_key'].extend  is not one operation, it's four (including the call itself). While somewhat simplified, the steps I listed are how Python actually executes the code, in that order. That is, the parameter of the function is evaluated between getting a pointer to the function and calling the function.

the output will be an empty dictionary because the list associated with the key 'old_key' has been moved to a new key 'old_key', and then the original key 'old_key' is removed. Therefore, after these operations, dict1 will be an empty dictionary.

This is not quite right, as the list is not "moved to a new key". The key is read once which resolves to a list, then the key is popped which returns the same list again, and deletes the key.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Aaron's explanation has made it clear, and I verified it by writing a sample code to demonstrate that the extend operation is indeed completed as expected, but the extended list is not referenced by any key in the dict.
To verify this, I wrote a custom class and a function that not only extends the list, but returns the list that is extended, and then I use an assignment in the same line to reassign the extended list to the same key. I could not have done this with the list.extend method without writing custom class, because the extend method returns None.
class MyList(list):
    def extend_and_return(self, iterable):
        self.extend(iterable)
        return self

def my_list_factory():
    return MyList()

dict2 = defaultdict(my_list_factory)

dict2['old_key'] = MyList([{'name': 'A'}])
dict2['old_key'] = dict2['old_key'].extend_and_return(dict2.pop('old_key'))
print(dict2)

