# Is there any danger in modifying a collection while iterating over it?

Tags: python

I have the following setup:

```
co_occurrences = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
# Populate the dictionary...

for word, occurrence_vector in co_occurrences:
    if word == "__length": continue

    for file_name, occurrence_count in occurrence_vector:
        co_occurrences[word][file_name] = occurrence_count / co_occurrences["__length"][file_name]
```

Is this line:

```
co_occurrences[word][file_name] = occurrence_count / co_occurrences["__length"][file_name]
```

dangerous? By dangerous, I mean that I want to iterate over each key once and only once, so any code that modfies this behavior is dangerous. I feel like it might be since I am modifying the data structure I am iterating over.

Comment: You can work around it by using `for word in co_occurrences.keys(): occurrence_vector=co_occurrences[word]` which makes a copy of the list of keys and iterates over that instead.

Comment: Also having a magic entry `"__length"` in your dict is really really weird. Just make a `file_length` dict that maps file names onto their lengths.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2315529/846892

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generally is fine, as was mentioned, the only issues come if the size of the dictionary changes.  If that happens, it will throw an `Exception` and stop executing, so if it executes without a `RuntimeError`, then whatever you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is only dangerous if you are changing the structure of the data you are iterating ie. adding / removing keys, otherwise it is completely fine to edit existing keys.